# SSIS Flat file source - text qualifier ignored when column has the delimiter char double

Tags: sql, csv, ssis

I have to import a flat file with SSIS. The column delimiter is a vertical bar `|` and a double quote `"` is the text qualifier.

There is one column that keeps bothering me, it has the delimiter double in it. And apparently SSIS ignores the text qualifiers when that occurs.

The file looks like this:

```
    colname1|colname2|colname3
    xxxx|"xxxx|xxxx"|xxxxx
    yyyy|"yyy||yyyy"|yyyyy
```

The first line with the x's goes fine, it imports 3 columns

```
xxxx   xxxx|xxxx   xxxxx
```

the second line however goes all wrong; instead of the expected (when I open as csv in Excel I get this)

```
yyyy   yyy||yyyy   yyyyy
```

it gives

```
yyyy   yyy         yyyy    yyyyy
```

Hope someone has a suggestion on how to solve this.

Comment: Don't open the file with excel.  Load it into a database table and then select the records.

Comment: Have a look here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/

Comment: I did it like that, but the textqualifiers are ignored when the pipe is double in the data.

Comment: We left out the column, so we don't have the problem anymore.